# javascript should i delete?

Tags: javascript, memory, backbone.js

I have some code like this:

```
var User = function () {
  _.bindAll(this)

  this.UserList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: UserModel
    // ...
  });

  this.UserListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  // ... etc
}

User.prototype.display = function() {
  var self = this
  self.collection = new self.UserList
  self.collection.fetch({
    success: function(collection, response) {
      self.users = new self.UserListView({
        collection: self.collection
      });
    }
  })
};


var user = new User()

route("users", function () {
  user.display()
})
```

My question is, is this going to cause memory issues? Every time the user arrives on the `user/:userPage` route the view, collection, etc are all going to be recreated. Will the old ones be deleted or do I have to delete it manually?

Should I be doing this:

```
User.prototype.display = function() {
  var self = this
  delete self.collection
  self.collection = new self.UserList
  self.collection.fetch({
    success: function(collection, response) {
      delete self.users
      self.users = new self.UserListView({
        collection: self.collection
      });
    }
  })
};
```

Also other general advice on my example code is appreciated too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is utterly useless:

```
   delete self.collection
   self.collection = new self.UserList
```

All `delete` does is remove `collection` field from the self object, and then you immediately recreate it.  Just do the assignment.

I think that you think that `delete self.collection` should somehow cause the garbage-collection of the object pointed to by the field.  It doesn't.

Also, don't use `self` as a variable name.  The browser uses it to mean, uh, something.

Comment: it does? what should i use instead?

Comment: `self` should be fine in most browsers. It's used globally as another reference to `window`

Comment: I'm sure it will be fine in any browser, but it might confuse the *reader* of the code.